# Numpy's __array_interface__ not returning dict

Tags: c++, python, boost, numpy, boost-python

I am using an external program to compute a matrix that is written in C++ and is interfaced with python through `boost::python`. I would like to pass this C array to numpy, and according to the authors this ability is already implemented with numpy's `obj.__array_interface__`. If I call this in a python script and assign the C++ object to `X` I obtain the following:

```
print X
#<sprint.Matrix object at 0x107c5c320>

print X.__array_interface__
#<bound method Matrix.__array_interface__ of <sprint.Matrix object at 0x107c5c320>>

print X.__array_interface__()
#{'shape': (5, 5), 'data': (4416696960, True), 'typestr': '<f8'}

print np.array(X)
#Traceback (most recent call last):
#  File "<string>", line 96, in <module>
#ValueError: Invalid __array_interface__ value, must be a dict
```

From my limited understanding I believe the problem is `X.__array_interface__` is not actually returning anything without the `()`. Is there a way to pass these arguments to `np.array` explicitly or a workaround for this issue.

I am really quite new to mixing C++ and python, if this makes no sense or if I need to expound on any part let me know!

Comment: `np.array` wants a dictionary. It looks like `X.__array_interface__()` returns a dictionary. So wouldn't `np.array(X.__array_interface__())` do it?

Comment: That was my initial thought also, but `np.array` wants an object with the dictionary in `__array_interface__`, see `http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html`. So `np.array(X.__array_interface__())` just returns the dictionary. Unfortunately `np.array` is actually a `shared object` and I lack the understanding to manipulate it.

Comment: ugly but how about assigning X.__array_interface__ = X.__array_interface__() ? If this fails you may have to delve into the c++ and construct a numpy array on that side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

__array_interface__ should be a property (instance variable), not a method. So in the C++, or wherever the 'sprint.Matrix' object is defined, change it so that instead of having:

```
print X.__array_interface__
#<bound method Matrix.__array_interface__ of <sprint.Matrix object at 0x107c5c320>>
```

you have

```
print X.__array_interface__
#{'shape': (5, 5), 'data': (4416696960, True), 'typestr': '<f8'}
```

An alternative would be to define a custom wrapper class:

```
class SprintMatrixWrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, sprint_matrix):
        self.__array_interface__ = sprint_matrix.__array_interface__()
```

and then simply do:

```
numpy.array(SprintMatrixWrapper(X))
```

Comment: Works great! I was really hoping that there was a way to feed the dictionary to `np.array`. I will give it a few days to accept your answer. +1